# Tomcat, web.xml, exclude path

Tags: tomcat6, web.xml

In my application, i need to process all the requests from users in a single servlet, however, i happen to have a folder with static content, which i would like to also serve statically.

In my web.xml file, i have the following:

`<servlet>
        <servlet-name>all</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>a.b.c.WidgetlistXml</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>all</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>`

Is there a way i can exclude, say, all .zip files from this?

PS. I know this has been asked on StackOverflow before, but the latest posts were from about 2006, and they also concerned Spring or other frameworks. I use none, and since 2006 something could have changed in url-patterns. By the way, finding the docs on web.xml is not that simple either.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set a `DefaultServlet` for your static contents. Here is an example: 
http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/default-servlet.html#where